# ReadProcessMemory dereferencing multi-level-pointers returning completely gibberish

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

So, while attempting some basic game memory manipulation, I have to dereference a multi-layer pointer. The first step (first dereference), it works fine and returns the right pointer (finding pointer to 0x98f278at 0x57b0b8). However, step 2 and 3, it comes with complete gibberish (suddenly to 0x768f00984710).

The code is following:

```
uintptr_t findDMAAddy(HANDLE hProc, uintptr_t ptr, std::vector<unsigned int> offsets){
uintptr_t addr = ptr;

std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << "Find DMAaddy start address: 0x" << std::hex << addr << std::endl;

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < offsets.size(); i++){
    ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (BYTE*)addr, &addr, sizeof(addr), 0);
    std::cout << "Dereferenced: 0x" << std::hex << addr << ". ";
    addr += offsets[i];
    std::cout << "Adding: " << std::hex  << offsets[i] << " (address now: 0x" << addr << ")" << std::endl;
}
std::cout << std::endl;
return addr;
```

}

Called by:

```
std::cout << "Player object pointer address: 0x" << std::hex << modBase << "(base) + 0x" << playerOffset << "(offset) -> 0x" << dynapicPtrBaseaddr << std::endl;

uintptr_t playerReferencedAddress = 0;
ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (BYTE*)dynapicPtrBaseaddr, &playerReferencedAddress, sizeof(playerReferencedAddress), 0);
std::cout << "Player addr: " << std::hex << playerReferencedAddress << std::endl;

//resolve our other things
std::vector<unsigned int> ammoShit = {0x374, 0x14, 0x0};
uintptr_t ammoAddr = findDMAAddy(hProc, dynapicPtrBaseaddr, ammoShit);
```

While, well, the pointer looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aDf9.png)

Console output is:

```
Module found: ac_client.exe, baseAddr: 0x400000
Player object pointer address: 0x400000(base) + 0x17b0b8(offset)     -> 0x57b0b8
Player addr: 98f278

Find DMAaddy start address: 0x57b0b8
Dereferenced: 0x98f278. Adding: 374 (address now: 0x98f5ec)
Dereferenced: 0x768f00984710. Adding: 14 (address now: 0x768f00984724)
Dereferenced: 0x768f00984724. Adding: 0 (address now: 0x768f00984724)

DynAddr: 0x57b0b8
ammoAddr = 0x768f00984724
Current ammo: 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I would think you would want to check the function return of ReadProcessMemory

Comment: Don't even know why I didn't think of that, will do.

Comment: Allright, so everyting started working when I changed from CLion to Visual Studio, and made it as x86. Weird